# Why is this regex incorrect?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}
```

Which is supposed to match dates that follow the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so 1990-01-01 should successfuly match. However this fails when I try it in javascript.

```
var x = new RegExp('\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}')
x.test('1990-02-01')    //why is this false?
```

Comment: Why not use regex literal syntax?

Comment: @pointy what do you mean?

Comment: this is quite neat on the surface but what if someone enters, say, 2018-02-31? That's not a valid date, but it passes the RegEx. I wouldn't try and validate dates using regexes. You could potentially account for the varying lengths of months with a more complex expression, but realistically you can't account for leap years. One technique is to use a date library which can tell you if a date is actually real or not, momentJS provides such functionality, for example.

Comment: `/\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regular js regex syntax. Like this:

```js
var x = /\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}/;
console.log(x.test('1990-02-01'));
```

if you want to keep the `new RegExp` part, you have to escape the string's backslashes:

```js
var x = new RegExp('\\d{4}(-\\d{2}){2}');
console.log(x.test('1990-02-01'));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. "Do Y instead" is not an answer to "Why does X not work?".

Comment: I noticed that and add an addition

Comment: Better, but it still doesn't explain what's wrong with OP's version.

Comment: No need to provide yet a millionth answer for a millionth dupe.